# why on back press this app with this logcat

Tags: java, android, android-studio, webview

I have just started android and I am making a webview app

My whole plan is to show the splash screen till webview loads then switch visiblity of somethings and then make the webview visible

The webview is visibled perfectly.

The webview is able to load new url that are clicked in itself but as soon as someone presses back button the app crashes. Why is this?

Another is I want to add a url filter that will not load any other url different from my website. I have seen some SO answers on how to that but they crashes my app as well. Here I removed that code for once. How can I implement this?

Here is my main activity

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private WebView wv;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        WebView wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.browser);
        wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        wv.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);


// also help in where to put the url filter thingy

        wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
              // this is where i change visiblity of splash page and else
            }


        });
        wv.setOverScrollMode(WebView.OVER_SCROLL_NEVER);
        wv.loadUrl("https://metv.ml");
    }
// this is the place where i tried putting the on back press code which crashes the app on going back
}
```

This is the code I was trying to use for going back according to webview history

```
    public void onBackPressed () {
        if (wv.canGoBack()) {
            wv.goBack();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
```

Log cat:

```
2019-10-18 00:48:02.916 3711-3711/com.example.metv E/InputEventSender: Exception dispatching finished signal.
2019-10-18 00:48:02.916 3711-3711/com.example.metv E/MessageQueue-JNI: Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback
2019-10-18 00:48:02.917 3711-3711/com.example.metv E/MessageQueue-JNI: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.webkit.WebView.canGoBack()' on a null object reference
        at com.example.metv.MainActivity.onBackPressed(MainActivity.java:33)
        at android.app.Activity.onKeyUp(Activity.java:3185)
        at android.view.KeyEvent.dispatch(KeyEvent.java:2743)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchKeyEvent(Activity.java:3503)
        at androidx.core.app.ComponentActivity.superDispatchKeyEvent(ComponentActivity.java:115)
        at androidx.core.view.KeyEventDispatcher.dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEventDispatcher.java:84)
        at androidx.core.app.ComponentActivity.dispatchKeyEvent(ComponentActivity.java:133)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.dispatchKeyEvent(AppCompatActivity.java:558)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchKeyEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:59)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl$AppCompatWindowCallback.dispatchKeyEvent(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:2814)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(DecorView.java:409)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processKeyEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5857)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:5715)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:5177)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:5237)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:5196)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:5363)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:5204)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:5420)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:5177)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:5237)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:5196)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:5204)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:5177)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:5237)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:5196)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:5396)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ImeInputStage.onFinishedInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5561)
        at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$PendingEvent.run(InputMethodManager.java:2848)
        at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.invokeFinishedInputEventCallback(InputMethodManager.java:2343)
        at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.finishedInputEvent(InputMethodManager.java:2334)
        at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$ImeInputEventSender.onInputEventFinished(InputMethodManager.java:2825)
        at android.view.InputEventSender.dispatchInputEventFinished(InputEventSender.java:141)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:326)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:189)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7183)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:576)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:942)
2019-10-18 00:48:02.917 3711-3711/com.example.metv D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
2019-10-18 00:48:02.920 3711-3711/com.example.metv E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.metv, PID: 3711
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.webkit.WebView.canGoBack()' on a null object reference
        at com.example.metv.MainActivity.onBackPressed(MainActivity.java:33)
        at android.app.Activity.onKeyUp(Activity.java:3185)
        at android.view.KeyEvent.dispatch(KeyEvent.java:2743)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchKeyEvent(Activity.java:3503)
        at androidx.core.app.ComponentActivity.superDispatchKeyEvent(ComponentActivity.java:115)
        at androidx.core.view.KeyEventDispatcher.dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEventDispatcher.java:84)
        at androidx.core.app.ComponentActivity.dispatchKeyEvent(ComponentActivity.java:133)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.dispatchKeyEvent(AppCompatActivity.java:558)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchKeyEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:59)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl$AppCompatWindowCallback.dispatchKeyEvent(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:2814)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(DecorView.java:409)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processKeyEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5857)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:5715)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:5177)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:5237)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:5196)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:5363)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:5204)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:5420)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:5177)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:5237)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:5196)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:5204)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:5177)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:5237)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:5196)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:5396)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ImeInputStage.onFinishedInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5561)
        at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$PendingEvent.run(InputMethodManager.java:2848)
        at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.invokeFinishedInputEventCallback(InputMethodManager.java:2343)
        at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.finishedInputEvent(InputMethodManager.java:2334)
        at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$ImeInputEventSender.onInputEventFinished(InputMethodManager.java:2825)
        at android.view.InputEventSender.dispatchInputEventFinished(InputEventSender.java:141)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:326)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:189)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7183)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:576)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:942)
```

Comment: remove `WebView` from this `WebView wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.browser);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> private WebView wv;
> ```

This is a field you never initialise.

> ```
>  public void onBackPressed () {
>     if (wv.canGoBack()) {
> ```

Here you're calling a method on the uninitialised field, hence the NPE.

> ```
> protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>     //...
>     WebView wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.browser);
> ```

This is a local variable you do initialise. Change the `WebView wv =` to just `wv =` to make it initialise your field instead of declaring and initialising a local variable.

Comment: that worked perfectly... can you also help me with the url filter thing so webview only loads url of my website and do absolutely nothing when clicked on a url with different url then my domain http://metv.ml